# How to test authentication with Google?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have a Rails app where login/logout is straight done by Devise.  However, I want to allow users to connect their Google Adwords account (using https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby) , therefore I have a controller that is responsible for letting user link its Google account. Here is how it looks:

```
def callback()
    api = get_adwords_api
    begin
      token = api.authorize(
          {
            :oauth2_callback => adwords_login_callback_url,
            :oauth2_verification_code => params[:code]
          }
      )
      current_user.update_attributes(:adwords_token => token[:access_token], :adwords_refresh_token => token[:refresh_token], :adwords_issued_at => token[:issued_at], :adwords_expires_in => token[:expires_in], :adwords_id_token => token[:id_token])
      flash.notice = 'Authorized successfully'
      redirect_to adwords_home_index_path
    rescue 
      flash.alert = 'Authorization failed'
      redirect_to adwords_login_prompt_path
    end
  end
```

And get_adwords_api looks like this:

```
def create_adwords_api
    config_filename = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'adwords_api.yml')
    api = AdwordsApi::Api.new(config_filename) # This is from the GEM
    return api
end
```

So, my question is:

How am I supposed to test that the User authentication goes smoothly and the model gets updated with the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your testing philosophy.  I personally would advise against calling external services from functional tests, and suggest using the mocking approach below or another mocking/stubbing approach.  Calling external services can be slow, subject to network flakiness (you could mock timeouts etc. by the way), be problematic for services with call quotas (perhaps not applicable in this case), and so on.  So, for your functional test you could mock the service so that it returns canned information.  This way you can check that you are passing the service sensible information and are doing the right thing with the results you get back.  You can also easily test any error situations.  For example, with Mocha you could do something like this in your functional test:

```
api = mock()
canned_auth_response = {:access_token => 'whatever-you-want', :refresh_token => 'blah', :issued_at => 'sometime', :expires_in => 'some-future-time', :id_token => 'some-id'}
api.expects(:authorize).with(has_entries(:oauth2_callback => 'your-url', :oauth2_verification_code => 'whatever-you-put-in-params-code').returns(canned_auth_response)
AdwordsApi::Api.expects(:new).with('your-config-filename').returns(api)
```

You'll now be getting a mocked api object back when your test calls `AdwordsApi::Api.new` which will return the canned `auth_response` data (change it to contain appropriate data for you of course), so you can now call your controller callback which will use the mock and then you can check your callback method does what you expect.  You can return bad data or incomplete data from the `api` mock , or get it to raise exceptions if that's something it could do in real life.  The `expects` also checks that you are passing the parameters you expect to the external service.

I'm not saying this is the only or the best way, or even that the above code is guaranteed to work as I just typed it out, but it should illustrate the approach!

If you actually want to test against the real service, which is a nice smoke test / sanity check, you could use the vcr gem https://github.com/vcr/vcr to do record/replay of http responses (I've never used it, but it looks good), or perhaps you could add a test that only runs when specifically requested, or automatically on a build server.  For example, I quote the following from a blog post by platformatec which suggests that in rspec you can do:

```
describe KittenInfo::Client, external: true do
  # …
end
```

Then, in your spec_helper.rb, just set:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.filter_run_excluding external: true
end
```

Now, running your specs will by default skip all groups that have :external set to true. Whenever you tweak the client, or in your builds, you can run those specific tests with:

```
$ rspec --tag external
```

See http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/10/filtering-examples-in-rspec/ for the full writeup on this rspec approach.

Comment: I have a question with this approach. If I am testing in a feature kind of test, how would I place the mock? I mean, when the user clicks on the 'Proceed' button, it will go on the flow of Google. How can I control that?

Comment: Good question. I haven't tried this. This is something like Capybara/Selenium where you're simulating user flow?  Try mocking whatever it is that sends the user to google so that it just redirects straight to your callback with the necessary parameters instead (even if it's a class in a gem, doesn't mean mocha can't mock it). Alternatively, the vcr gem I mentioned, or something like it, looks like it can record the real http request/response and then replay it in subsequent test runs (and re-run the real req./resp. at a configurable interval to make sure your tests don't diverge from reality).

Comment: Interesting. I think I will just create a question with the rspec and my controller code so you, or somebody else can help me with a better specific question. Thanks!